# display a bg image in table view for iphone

Tags: iphone

i can display BG image in table view  cell but when i click any cell there is a blue color filling all my cell and my images just goes behind  now i want to show my image in front of that blue color how to do that??

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SuperCell.png"]] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

and

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SuperCell.png"]] autorelease];
```